# Generating Bundle in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, bundles

Can't find a solution for this on stack.

I'm using ubuntu server,

```
$php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=WMDN/FirstBundle --format=yml
```

goes fine until :

```
Generating the bundle code: OK
Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED
Confirm automatic update of your Kernel [yes]? yes
Enabling the bundle inside the Kernel: OK
Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]? yes
Importing the bundle routing resource: OK


 The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
You must do the following changes manually.


- Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
namespace in the "autoload" section:
```

I thought it was permissions, and set the whole dir to 775 and made sure owner was good.
I thought it was outdated bug for symfony and deleted whole dir, and got 2.4.4

I'm following a tutorial and their bundle generates just fine and I'd like mine to do it as well.

Why can it not autoload? My Namespace should be good to use. I cannot figure it out.
I have composer installed.

Following this tutorial series : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIcY5YYfZ14 and I'd really like to get my first bundle created so I may continue.

In conclusion, what are the reasons a bundle would fail autoload?

Comment: Did you install composer?

Comment: As it says in my post I have composer installed. Are there any commands I should run in composer first? I may be confused I installed composer before setting up symfony. Do I have to install it in my symfony dir as well?

Comment: I would give a `php composer.phar update` a whirl.

Comment: I installed composer and updated it in my symfony root folder. I deleted my previous bundle and cleared my cache. I checked localhost/config.php and there are no errors. I tried to generate a bundle and recieved the same error

Comment: Try adding --dir=src to your command.  The error about not being able to update composer.json is puzzling since it does not need updating it in the first place.  If --dir does not help then just run app/console generate:bundle and follow the prompts.

Comment: Cerad, I think what you said was the problem, but I handled it differntly. With the above command in my post, during dialogue I the dir was set to `/var/www/html/learn/app/cache/src/` and I told it `/var/www/html/learn/src/` and it went through all the way. 

So this was the solution for me I'll give you answer credits if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per to comments, solution was to set the --src parameter correctly.